# Update array with new ObjectID and $currentDate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

i have a array in my mongo database with my users. On register i'm adding a new user ( object ) to this array of users. At the same time i want to create a `ObjectID` to this new user and create a `created_at` attribute with the date it was created

```
let NewUserStructure = {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    username: NewUserUsername,
    nome: NewUserName,
    password: password,
    logado: false,
    especialidades: EspecialidadesArray,
    adm: isadmin,
    cuidade: [],
    $currentDate: {criadoem: true},
    criadopor: createdby,
};
// let query = {_id: '5b193acdfb6fc05a6fe42785'};
let query = {Profissionais: {$exists: true}};
let NewValue = {$addToSet: {Profissionais: NewUserStructure}};
nosqlquery.update('usuarios', query, NewValue, function(result) {
    res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

I created a generic function for **update method on another file**

```
const update = function(targetcollection, query, NewValues, callback) {
console.log('update was called');
_db.collection(targetcollection).updateOne(query, NewValues, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(result);
});
```

};

`NewUserStructure` is the json i'm inserting on the Profissionais array using `$addToSet`. I tried to create that unique ObjectID and a new attribute with currentDate from many different ways.

Error : `$currentDate is not valid for storage.`

I feel that creating a `_id` field with `ObjectID()` would not create a unique _id for the user, is there another approach for this also?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `$currentDate` operator within an `$addToSet`, so just use `new Date()` instead, similar to what you're doing with the call to `ObjectID()` (which is fine):

```
let NewUserStructure = {
    _id: ObjectID(),
    username: NewUserUsername,
    nome: NewUserName,
    password: password,
    logado: false,
    especialidades: EspecialidadesArray,
    adm: isadmin,
    cuidade: [],
    criadoem: new Date(),
    criadopor: createdby,
};
```